# How to mock static access to spring-managed @Bean with Mockito?

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, spring-boot-test

I have a `@Service` bean that I need `static` access to:

```
@Service
public class MyBean implements InitializingBean {
    private static MyBean instance;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static MyBean get() {
        return instance;
    }

    public String someMethod(String param) {
       return "some";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Service
public class OtherService {
    public static void makeUse() {
        MyBean myBean = MyBean.get();
    }
}
```

Problem: when I write an integration `junit` test for `OtherService` that makes use of the stat `MyBean` access, the `instance` variable is always null.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ITest {
    @Autowired
    private OtherService service;

    @MockBean
    private MyBean myBean;

    @Before
    public void mock() {
        Mockito.when(myBean.someMethod(any()).thenReturn("testvalue");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        service.makeUse(); //NullPointerException, as instance is null in MyBean
    }
}
```

**Question:** how can I write an integration test when using such type of static access to a spring-managed bean?

Comment: My first Question is why do you access the bean via a static field when the user of the bean is also spring managed? You can inject the singelton instance by spring

Comment: This is just an example. In my code the hierarchy is much deeper, and at some stage I need access to that service inside a static class. To access the `MyBean` always in the same way, I just used the `instance` access everywhere. So maybe I have to rephrase my question in: how to test and mock a static accessed method?

Comment: Don't use static singletons!!! They are nasty and evil!!!

Comment: You can use [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockstatic) but IMHO you don't need static singeltons

Comment: But: imagine I have a static utility method that needs to obtain a variable from a `@Service` class. I cannot inject the service there, so have to provide static access to that service somehow... how could I solve that without static access to the spring-managed service?

Comment: If your utility method needs something, then it should/must expect that as a parameter. Accessing a Spring Bean directly from that util method is dirty and broken design.

Comment: "imagine I have a static utility method that needs to obtain a variable from a @Service class" Then that utility should NOT be static. It should also be declared in spring and have the service injected

Comment: Ok you convinced me that wanting to mock a static method during testing is probably already a design smell. So I should rewrite my utility to either a) take the service as additional parameter, or b) not being an utility, but a service itself.

Comment: Correct. That's one of the great advantages of testing: Code smells are much easier to find as soon as testing becomes strangely complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to influence the `@Bean`-creation, then use `@Configuration`

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return new MyBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public OtherService otherService () {
        return new OtherService(myBean());
    }
}
```

Then mocking becomes really easy:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ITest {
    @MockBean
    private MyBean myBean;

    @Autowired
    private OtherService service;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // service is initialised with myBean
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When more control is needed, then you can choose the following approach. It provides sometimes more control than just a @MockBean. In your test you can easily mock a method just before calling it. This is my preferred way.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    ...    
    @Bean
    public MyBean getMyBean() {
        return mock( MyBean.class);
    }
    @Bean
    public OtherService otherService () {
        return new OtherService( getMyBean());
    }
}
```

In the application you can use @Autorwired to access it AND implement method overrule/mocking easily.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AnotherTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean;

    @Autowired
    private OtherService service;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        when( myBean.method( a, b)).thenReturn( something);
        service.doSomething( ....); // with myBean.method() overruled 
    }
}
```